# Using AJAX responses to minimize further requests in SPA

Tags: javascript, ajax, mongodb, express, mean-stack

I'm making an ecommerce app (MEAN) and keep running into the same question as I make AJAX http requests. I'm using MEAN, and the single page architecture is fundamental to this question.

I've read that http requests should only be used if absolutely necessary, but I'm wondering how far that goes. Should I be harvesting all information returned by necessary http requests and using it to reduce further requests, or will this kind of thinking just lead to complicated code and very little performance benefit?

For instance, I have an addToCart method that makes a `post` request. Within the `post`, it first checks the `product` database to ensure the item has enough quantity in stock, then it checks the `user` database to make sure it is not already in the cart before adding it.

Post Request:

```
 .post(auth, function(req, res, next){
   var newCartItem = {
    product: req.body._id,
    quantity: req.body.quantity
  };

  function addCartItem(){
    //Checks user.cart.product to ensure that item isn't already in cart
    User.update({username: req.payload.username, 'cart.product': {$ne: newCartItem.product}},
      {$push: {cart: newCartItem}},
      function(err, user){
        if(err){return next(err);}
        if(!user.nModified){
          res.json({message: 'Item is already in your cart.'});
        }else{
          res.json({message: 'Item added to cart', addedProduct: newCartItem});
        }
      }
    );
  }
  //Checks product database to ensure sufficient inventory(quantity)
  Product.update({_id:req.body._id, quantity: {$gte: req.body.quantity}}, {$inc:{quantity: -req.body.quantity}},
    function(err, product){
      if(err) {
        return next(err);
      }else if(product.nModified === 0) {
        res.json({message: 'Product no longer has sufficient quantity in stock.'});
      }else{
        addCartItem();
      }
  });
```

If I *really* want to minimize http requests, I could have the `Product.update` callback return the product information to the client (within `res.json`), which could then be used for subsequent checks on the inventory of that particular product on the client side before making the server request. Further, if inventory is sufficient and the product is added to cart, I could have the `User.update` callback return the `user.cart` so that the client-side would then have knowledge, and validate that the item being added is not in the user's cart  before sending any subsequent requests.

This sort of question at first seemed like an isolated case, until I started seeing it pop up everywhere. I know this is somewhat opinion-based, but I have run into this basic question in so many situations that I'm taking the risk of being flamed.

To reiterate, here is my question:
Should I be harvesting any possible information returned by necessary http requests and using it to reduce further requests, or will this kind of thinking just lead to complicated code and very little performance benefit?

Cheers!
Tyler

Answer (score 1):

You're on MEAN stack , which implies that you need to export your data from the backend to the frontend via webservices ( REST mostly ) , and you can easily do that by generating the json objects when accessing some routes thus creating a RESTful API.
That API would be consumed in the SPA made in AngularJS either via the $http or the $resource modules.(angular-resource in not built-in).
Eitherway, you need to configure the states (and not the routes) , so that your state machine calls data related to the requested state in the app , and it does it asnychronously,by default.
if you really want to "stop hitting the backend" with your AJAX , you need to use the $provider as it runs only once , and the app would be getting data from that data provider that is in fact holding data it got from the webservice.(you need to do that).
you would also like to reduce the POST methods in your SPA , as there is no way to reduce the load (unless you're looking for an infrastructure solution AKA nginx as a defacto solution..).
Good luck..